# SCNPhysicsBody calls contact delegate but does not make a collision at high speed?

Tags: swift, collision-detection, scenekit

I was making a test "breaker" game in SceneKit and tried speeding up the ball. At a certain point, the ball would consistently pass through my boundaries. Not quite sure why, I slowed down to 1 FPS and took this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

When looking at Apple's docs:

> A small body might move so fast that it completely passes through
>   another physics body without ever having a frame of animation where
>   the two touch each other.

However, it is
 clear that the ball is touching the boundary, yet still passes through. The contact delegate will also register a collision. This is with an x-velocity and z-velocity of 50-100 each. Shouldn't this scenario cause the ball to bounce back, as the frame rendered with the ball touching the obstacle? And along with this, how would I check super fast collisions as such in SceneKit? I heard that in SpriteKit, one can use `usesPreciseCollisionDetection`, but this doesn't seem to be the case in SceneKit.

To give an exact idea of what the boundaries look like, they are two cylinders with no space in between.

[image]
Edit: Seems like changing the physics shape on the boundary to either convex or concave instead of bounding box helps, but does NOT completely prevent a contact registering but a collision not happening. Same if I create a new obstacle - it'll pass through at high enough speeds while still registering contact delegate. Any theories on why?

Edit 2: From the comment on this question, here is a screenshot of where `didBegin` is called by setting a breakpoint. You can see that the ball is just leaving the barrier. It starts passing through when x-velocity or z-velocity is set to about 29-40 and is completely unreliable as to whether it passes through or not after that. Always though, `didBegin` is called, but not always `didEnd`
[image]

Comment: Hmm not sure, but just a shot of an Idea that may help you... I think that the boundaries are too thin for SceneKit physics to detect collision on high speed - You could make an invisible boxes to use as a boundaries that will be thick enough -- if i doesn't work - you just can make this collision test your self per frame the bounce back logic is not that physically complicated.
I think that the collision is not happening because `SCNPhysicsEngine` won't handle collisions when one body is inside the other body_

Comment: @ColdSteel thank you for the suggestion, however it seems like it still passes through a large object in the way. Any reason why the contact delegate fires but not the collision?

Comment: you don't have infinite control over the frame rate,  this is discretized time and depending upon the precision of the drawing it might look to be touching but probably isn't, you would have to dump out a list of actual points and not just a visual inspection.  the apple stuff is very rudimentary, it's nowhere near a real 3D tool like autocad or ProE.

Comment: Thank you @GAlexander, can you explain though why the contact delegate would register? It must know there was a collision.

Comment: what delegate methods did you code? didbegin? didend? didupdate? add some debug each, dump out the bitmasks, positions, etc  use a solid object with a fine mesh, not a shell object.

Comment: @GAlexander so I coded the didbegin and it registers the correct bitmask when it begins the collision with the ball. Any more that I should try to debug?

Comment: @GAlexander here is my code (I'm using a tutorial so you need to change the linear speed of the ball) https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbxh4rg0qhpgxmy/Breaker.zip?dl=0 - but it seems like the didBegin contact is happening right as the ball is leaving (http://i.imgur.com/nYnchaa.png) after setting the breakpoint.

Comment: @rb612 did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm running into similar issues when two objects make contact at higher velocity, the didBeginContact fires up with a delay (after the objects are intersected already)

Comment: @mike_t unfortunately not - it seems that this hasn't been worked out well enough in XCode in comparison to Unity. :(

Comment: Is there some solution about that? I have two spheres and when the one is in high velocity is passing through inside of another and contact is detected but collide is not happening.